# What's the best practice for finding an object in a List based on one of object's properties?

Tags: c#, linq, artificial-intelligence, a-star

I'm trying to implement AI's A star algorithm in C#. As all of you may know, there is some place in my code where I want to check if a `Node` object (which I've defined in my code) is in my `List<Node> nodes` or not. But since the `Node` object in the `List<Node> nodes` has different reference with the one I've created to see if exists in the list, the output I get is `False`. (You can see this in the code below) :

```
class Node
{
    bool[,] state;
    Node parent;
    String action;
    int path_cost=0;
    public int Cost
    {
        get
        {
            return path_cost;
        }
    }
    public Node (bool[,] map)
    {
        this.state = map;
    }
    public double Heuristic()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool[,] a = new bool[,] { { false, false }, { true, true } };
        bool[,] a1 = new bool[,] { { false, false }, { true, true } };
        Node temp = new Node(a);

        Node n = new Node(a);
        Node n1 = new Node(a1);
        List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
        nodes.Add(n);
        Console.WriteLine(nodes.Contains(n1));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I've read about it and I know I should use `LINQ` and it's `WHERE` function. As you can see in my code, I want to check for `n1`'s existence based on `Node`'s `state` property which is a 2-dimensional array of booleans. Is using `WHERE` function best practice we can have here? I mean isn't there any problems with using it in my case?

Comment: "Where" is a linear search; unless you have reason to believe that the item will be found near the front of the list, on average you will search half the list before you find it. If you need it to be faster than that, then you're going to have to be more clever than the naive "where".

Comment: Typically for A-star you'd use a set, not a list, with the set indexed on the (unique valued) property you care about. That's sublinear search.

Comment: @EricLippert yeah that's right we should use a set. But unfortunately there is no "set" data structure in c#. What should I do then...??

Comment: @rthenamvar There are in fact set data structures in C#; a number of them in fact.

Comment: First, why would you think there is no set data structure in C#? Second, suppose there were no such structure. What might you do about it? I'll tell you what I do if the data structure I need does not exist: **I implement it**. You're a computer programmer; write some code!

Comment: Hm, are you sure there's no set structure in C#?  I'm looking right at the `HashSet<T>` class.

Comment: @EricLippert so many thanks for your response. But in my case I'm trying to solve car blockade in a parking problem. (there is a red car, which we aim to open way for it to go out of the parking). So in every state, I try to store the map of the parking (which is my state) in a 2D array of booleans. What else I can do...??

Comment: There are any number of things to do. As Joel notes, you could implement your own equality and hash algorithm. Or you could abandon arrays and go with something like an immutable memoized Boolean quad tree, which would possibly greatly save on memory.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Where()`, I'd use `Any()`, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(nodes.Any(n => ... ));
```

The trick here is the `...`. You mentioned comparing based on a 2D state array, but not what that comparison should look like. Does every item need to match? That seems... expensive. Is there a faster comparison? Have you thought about overriding `.Equals()`/`GetHashCode()`?

Additionally, depending on the size and nature of your List, you might do better with either a `Dictionary` or `HashSet`, both of which can potentially do much better than `Any()`.

Finally, pay attention to the comments on your question from Eric Lippert. He's worked on a the C# team at Microsoft, and has a blog where he's [already implemented A*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/02/path-finding-using-a-in-c-3-0-part-one/). That ought to be a great reference for you.

Comment: Yes I checked out Eric Lippert's solution. But my problem is much more complex. The problem I'm solving is cars blockade in a parking. So I should store the map of the parking (which is my state) in a 2D array of booleans. A* should check if a node with same node exists in the list. What else I can do...??